# Inconsistenty "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on primary key of AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-identity, nullreferenceexception

We're getting the classic null reference exception, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Nothing unusual there, except it's happening on an IdentityUser that's come straight from the context.

The line triggering the exception is:

```
allUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == log.ActionByUserId)
```

and the exception is triggered at u.Id. How could u ever be null in this scenario? This suggests to me that one of the entries in allUsers is null, but I don't understand how that would happen when allUsers is pulled from the database by Entity Framework. This is happening on a read-only Controller Action, so we haven't tried to create a user earlier in the request.

This error is happening intermittently on our production instance, but doesn't happen when we restore the same database to a development environment.

More code for context (although I have simplified this code to the relevant sections too):

Context (the ApplicationUser class has it's own context, separate to the context shared by most of our other entities):

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class UserService 
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetUsers()
    {
        var contextUsers = _context.Users;
        return contextUsers;
    }
}
```

Domain object

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // Id is inherited from IdentityUser
}
```

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult ParticipantLog(int participantId)
{
    var allUsers = UserService.GetUsers();
    var log = LogService.GetParticipantLog(participantId);
    var model = ParticipantLogsModelMapper.Create(log, allUsers);
}
```

Mapper:

```
public static ParticipantLogsViewModel Create(ParticipantLog log, IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> allUsers)
{
    var actionBy = allUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == log.ActionByUserId);
    var model = new ParticipantLogViewModel
    {
        ActionBy = actionBy.DisplayName
    };

    return model;
}
```

Comment: Why you can be sure about the line number, even which variable that is null? Do you able to attach debugger to production server?

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo It's an internal application. We return full error messages when there is an exception.

Comment: Assuming that line is the actual culprit, I will suspect at the `log` and `allUsers` variables first. There are another possible issue though, e.g. thread-safety issue - since ASP web use multi-threaded model.

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo The error message says line x, column y, with y being where u.Id is. It could be a thrad-safety issue.

Answer (score 2):

From:

```
allUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == log.ActionByUserId)
```

If `allUsers` doesn't contain any records, then `default(T)` is returned, which in this instance will be `null`.

I've put together a minimal console app (pulling in a reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = default(ApplicationUser);
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // Id is inherited from IdentityUser
}
```

And `p` is indeed null. The `FirstOrDefault` extension method, by its very nature, will either return the *first* element in the `IEnumerable`, or the default for the `<T>` if there's nothing in the list, which appears to be what's happening in this case.

> This error is happening intermittently on our production instance, but doesn't happen when we restore the same database to a development environment.

Where you've simplified the code that you've shown, have you elided some error checking/handling that's resulting in a *failed* attempt to retrieve user details from the database returning an empty set? That's one way you could be seeing the scenario that is occurring here.

To help narrow this down, in production, you could put a diagnostic logging line in above the `allUsers.FirstOrDefault` call that checks `allUsers.Any()` to confirm that there are items present in `allUsers` and then try to tie this back to any other diagnostics you have. The problem with development environments is, whilst they've seldom got as much *oomph* as production, they usually have a miniscule amount of load, in comparison. This results in issues that occur due to operating under load just not being picked up =(

Comment: It's not p being null that's my problem, it's u. I'm getting the null reference error *inside* the FirstOrDefault. I'm OK with p (actionBy) being null if it can't find a user with the given ID.

Comment: @Rob No error checking removed. _context.Users is populated by EF and passed around unmodified until the line throwing the exception.

Comment: @thelem, mea culpa, I conflated a few things and ended up with a duff answer - the only other thing I can think of / suggest is that allUsers *must* have a null ApplicationUser in it. How is your application composed? Is there a possibility that more than one request is sharing the same ApplicationDbContext and some book-keeping "under the hood" is breaking, e.g. a user has been deleted on another request which has invalidated that particular user and this is being mirrored across to your IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> ?

Answer (score 0):

By profiling the database server I noticed that the problem line:

```
allUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == log.ActionByUserId)
```

is enumerating the whole table behind allUsers. I was expecting it instead to just retrieve the row for the relevant user.

I think this is because allUsers are IdentityUser objects, rather than standard EF domain objects, and u.Id is of type TKey rather than a standard primitive.

My workaround is intead of passing in an IEnumerable I'm passing in my UserService, which includes a method for calling FindById on UserManager

```
class UserService
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public UserService(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
    }

    public ApplicationUser Find(string userId)
    {
        return _userManager.FindById(userId);
    }
}
```